# Issue creating a Timestamp (somewhat) during DST

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, dst

I am struggling with a problem. The more I investigate and debug it, the more I think that I might not understand it completely.

My timezone is ET (UTC -5). The hour is somewhere between 21:00 and 21:59. The date is March 8th 2014. In this timezone, DST happens on March 9th 2014 when 1:59:59 becomes 3:00:00.

I want to persist the current date time as a `Timestamp` in the DB with Hibernate. For this I use Jadira's PersistentDateTime class. I persist UTC values, so Jadira changes the current date time (let's say March 8th 2014 21:30 ET) to March 9th 2014 02:30 UTC which is correct. Then it constructs a `Timestamp` from the string representation of the UTC date time and the `Timestamp` is `09-MAR-14 03.30.00.000000000 AM`. When I go back to the ET representation, I get March 8th 2014 22:30 ET.

As far as I understand, this is wrong - I should get the same date time.

It seems to me, that when creating a `Timestamp`, DST is applied, although it should not be. I am considering one detail: ET is UTC -5. 21:00 is exactly the hour when DST occurs in ET minus 5 hours. So 21:30 ET is 2:30 UTC. 2:30 is an invalid our in ET, on March 8th. Maybe this has to do with the strange behavior.

I am using jadira 1.9 (usertype.joda-time-1.9.jar and usertype.spi-1.9.jar) and Hibernate 3.6.0. My model is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = RUN_STATUS_DATA_DB_TABLE_NAME)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class StatusData implements Identifiable, Serializable {

    ...

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(name = RUN_STATUS_COLUMN_POST_EXECUTION_END_TIME)
    public DateTime getPostExecutionEndTime() {
        return postExecutionEndTime;
    }

    public void setPostExecutionEndTime(DateTime postExecutionEndTime) {
        this.postExecutionEndTime = postExecutionEndTime;
    }
}
```

The Jadira code that creates the unexpected Timestamp is in [this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.jodatime/1.9/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/columnmapper/TimestampColumnDateTimeMapper.java?av=f), at line 72

Any thought on why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Some terminology corrections: ET = (EST *and* EDT).  EST = -5, EDT = -4.  But that doesn't explain why your timestamp was at 3:30 UTC instead of 2:30 UTC.   **Please show your code**.  Otherwise it is impossible to help you further.

Comment: What version of Jadira are you using, and which database?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the requested details.

Comment: That's a very old version of Usertype (and Hibernate). Can you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

There have been lots of enhancements and fixes since the version of Usertype you are using.

I have backported as much of the functionality as possible to Hibernate 3.6 and Java 5. You can use this backport by using the module usertype.core-hibernate36.

Currently you will need to build this from source until the next release. Get the sources from https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira

Also, take a look at the documentation at http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html

Let me know if you encounter any issues.

Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira.